# d3 filtering function not working based on attribute

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Hey so I cannot seem to figure out this issue. Basically my goal for this predicament is when the item is dragged over the div element I want it to return the element that closely responds with the div element.

I set attributes to the div element in correspondence with its coordinates like so.

```
chars = grid
            .selectAll("svg")
            .data(data.nodes)
            .enter()
            .append("div")
            .attr("class", "gridData")
            .attr("gridX", function(d) {return d.x})
            .attr("gridY", function(d) {return d.y})
            .on('contextmenu', function () {
                d3.event.preventDefault()
            }).call(drag);
```

When I use the drag end function I want to grasp the element that corresponds with the coordinates like so.

```
drag.on('dragend', function(d) {
            var hx = helper.datum().x;
            var hy = helper.datum().y;
            d.x = hx;
            d.y = hy;
            d3.select(this).transition().duration(100).style('left', d.x + 'px').style('top', d.y + 'px')
                .each('end', function () {
                    helper.remove();
                });
            if (d.sample === "sample1") {
                var selection = d3.selectAll(".gridData").filter("gridX", d.x);
                console.log(selection);
                d3.select(this).remove();
            }
        });
```

Except my filter function is empty. I cannot figure out why the filter function is empty. The selection all returns an Array of 20 containers that has all the corresponding x and y coordinates. So I figured it should return.

Comment: Although not wrong per se, your `grid.selectAll("svg")...append("div")` looks like you were appending HTML to SVG which will not work this way. Then, in your drag handler the use of `selection.filter()` is not correct. Have a look at the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_filter). For more assistance it will be very helpful if you could set up a [mcve].

Comment: Ah ya so I changed a couple of things, thanks for the advice. Changing the element into a div element worked for filtering.